# How to use Linq to Xml with several levels in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So i've created a xml with several levels inside a "root" element. Basicly this is how it looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Collectibles>
  <SaveAltars>
    <SaveAltar>
      <Location>
        <row>0</row>
        <col>1</col>
      </Location>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Collected />
    </SaveAltar>
    <SaveAltar>
      <Location>
        <row>0</row>
        <col>3</col>
      </Location>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Collected />
    </SaveAltar>
  <Fruits>
    <Fruit>
      <Location>
        <row>0</row>
        <col>1</col>
      </Location>
      <Quantity>7</Quantity>
      <Collected />
    </Fruit>
    <Fruit>
      <Location>
        <row>0</row>
        <col>4</col>
      </Location>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <Collected />
    </Fruit>
  </Fruits>
  <Lizards>
    <Lizard>
      <Location>
        <row>0</row>
        <col>1</col>
      </Location>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Collected />
    </Lizard>
    <Lizard>
      <Location>
        <row>0</row>
        <col>3</col>
      </Location>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Collected />
  </Lizards>
</Collectibles>
```

And i also have simples classes like this:

```
class Fruit
{
    public string Col;
    public string Row;
    public string Quantity;
    public string Collected;

}
```

And i'm willing to make a list of Fruits/Lizard/SaveAltars using linQ To Xml But i don't know how do you have to proceed to read every level of the collectibles list. Like reading one Fruit then save it into a classe and put it in a list.

How can i achieve this please?

Right now i tried something like

```
    XDocument collectXml = XDocument.Load("collect.xml");
    foreach (XElement elem in collectXml.Descendants("Collectibles").Descendants("SaveAltars"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(elem.Descendants("Location").Descendants("row").ToString());
    }
```

But it shows some random code, i don't know how to populate a classe and save it in a list for every element in the xml file :/

Can u please help?

Comment: "But it shows some random code" - what *exactly* do you mean? What did you expect it to show, given that `Descendants()` returns a *sequence* of elements?

Comment: (As an aside, I would strongly recommend that you use data types other than string where appropriate... in this case `int` and `bool` look appropriate.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I need string value. And it shows only once (i expected it to show for every element) a xML command line not the value of the element i wanted. And most importatnly the loop is only done once to for every element

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need string value"? Do you mean you need a single string value for the whole set of fruit? Or you need string fields in the `Fruit` class for some reason? Not sure what you mean by "a xML command line" either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var fruit = collectXml
    .Descendants("Fruit")
    .Select(x => new Fruit {
        Col = (string) x.Element("Location").Element("Col"),
        Row = (string) x.Element("Location").Element("Row"),
        Quantity = (string) x.Element("Quantity"),
        Collected = x.Element("Collected") == null ? "Yes" : "No"
    })
    .ToList();
```

As noted in a comment though, you should *really* consider using more appropriate types - you possibly want a `Location` type for the location (with `int` values for `Row` and `Column`), an `int` for `Quantity`, and probably `bool` for `Collected`. Oh, and I'd strongly recommend using properties rather than public fields.

Comment: Exactly what i asked Thank you! Can you explain me why .Descendants("fruit") get directly into the Fruits level? I thought i have firstly reach "Fruits" and then asked for loop trough "fruit"

Comment: @user5014677: I suggest you read the documentation for Descendants and Elements.

Comment: Descendants is any child while element is only the first level child.  The tags <Fruits> and <SaveAltars> are not necessary.  You can have an array of elements at the same level.  I usually recommend eliminating the  extra level of tags.